# Compare the first 3 cells of three columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hello I have three columns with filled with names. So far I need to extract the three first cells of each column and put all the 15 names into a forth column. But if there are duplicates I must not put them in the list.

So far I got into

```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim temp(15) As String
Dim array1(5) As String
Dim array2(5) As String
Dim array3(5) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 1 To 5
    array1(i) = Cells(i + 3, 1).Value
    array2(i) = Cells(i + 3, 4).Value
    array3(i) = Cells(i + 3, 7).Value
Next i

temp(1) = array1(1)
temp(2) = array1(2)
temp(3) = array1(3)
temp(4) = array1(4)
temp(5) = array1(5)
temp(6) = array2(1)
temp(7) = array2(2)
temp(8) = array2(3)
temp(9) = array2(4)
temp(10) = array2(5)
temp(11) = array3(1)
temp(12) = array3(2)
temp(13) = array3(3)
temp(14) = array3(4)
temp(15) = array3(5)

For i = 1 To 15
    For j = 1 To 15
        If (temp(i) = temp(j + 1)) Then
        Else
        Cells(i + 4, 10).Value = temp(i)
        End If
    Next j
    j = 0
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You have 3 columns, and need to extract the first 3 cells of each column. That is 9 cells. Where do you get 15 names? Did you mean to extract first 5 cells of each column?

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 1 to 3
   Cells(6 * i - 5, 10).Resize(5, 1).Value = Cells(6 * i - 5, 4 * i - 3).Resize(5,1).Value
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Cells(1, 10).Resize(15, 1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```